# Metal antenna enclosure and grounding

Tags: rf, noise, grounding

I have designed a device with a metal enclosure. It has an external antenna with a connector mounted on the box.

[image]

The antenna ground and box are connected. Moreover, the antenna is mounted on the tower and connected to the device using a coaxial cable. The enclosure body, coaxial cable ground, and antenna ground are connected to the tower (tower material is metal).

It is like this device:

[image]

The tower doesn't have any earthing accessories, so it's very noisy.

When I mount the device enclosure and the antenna on the tower, the RF coverage becomes very low with respect to when when I put isolators between the tower and "enclosure+antenna" mounting clamps.

Is it possible to make the device robust with respect to tower noise without isolators?

Comment: Can you provide some information on the antenna?  And the metal box should be grounded.

Comment: @SteveSh as you see in the picture, the antenna is an omni-directional antenna. the antenna is fixed by clamping the metal part of the antenna to the tower. the metal part of the antenna is connected to antenna GND.

Comment: Can you run a ground wire from the RF source to the tower?

Comment: Is the antenna a monopole, requiring a ground plane, or is it "ground independent" (such as a coaxial dipole within the sheath)? Is there a nearby strong interference source?

Comment: You state "metal container"... but is it *bare* metal? It looks to be painted or enameled white, and if that's nonconductive, you need to make a better connection.

Comment: @Aaron, actually the ground connection of the device is tied to device chassis (enclosure) and it tied to the tower (which is not grounded to earth)

Comment: @MarkLeavitt, the antenna is dipole.  maybe there is an interference source. but my device has ethernet connection too. when I connect device to the tower, the ethernet connection becomes unstable. it seems that a conductive noise is induced to supply routing which make ethernet IC operation unstable.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, the eclosure (container) is not painted in the connections and the connection exists between antenna "connector and container" and "container and tower"